# Php foreach, print a list

Tags: php

Trying to print out an array in a list with html and php.
The code I use for it:

```
<ul>
<?php
    foreach ($arrayData as $cart):
        echo '<li>',$cart['name'], $cart['price'], $cart['amount'],'</li>';
    endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

This dosen't work, also it makes the rest of the site (footer) to not e shown at all.

Also, this will make the same problem and make the rest of the site not appear.

```
<?php
    foreach ($arrayData as $cart):
        echo $cart['name'];
    endforeach;
?>
```

If I insted use a var_dump and print out $cart I get the hole array pinted out, so I got data in the array.

The var_dump code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($arrayData as $cart):
        var_dump($cart);
    endforeach;
?>
```

Output from var_dump:

```
object(Product)#1 (4) 
{ 
    ["id":"Product":private]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["name":"Product":private]=> string(8) "Xbox One"
    ["price":"Product":private]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["amount"]=> int(55) 
}
```

Comment: Is there any error you get?

Comment: @C0dekid No, noting...

Comment: Add your var dump of `$arrayData`

Comment: echo "<li>".$cart['name'] .",". $cart['price'] .",". $cart['amount'] ."</li>";

Comment: the problem is in your quotes

Comment: error reporting should be throwing you something like `unexpected ,`.... and you're not checking for errors, that's what they're "no errors".

Comment: @J-CFOREST you should have popped that in as an answer, IMHO along with a good explanation.

Comment: @Jeppezon can you show us the output of `var_dump($cart);` ? Or at least `var_dump($cart['name'], $cart['price'], $cart['amount'])` ?

Comment: @J-CFOREST hold on, OP says it still doesn't work

Comment: @Fred-ii- don't have access to the server running the site.

Comment: share `print_r($arrayData)` ?

Comment: we have no idea what `$arrayData` is. So, if you don't have access, then catch and display errors `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and look at your html source.

Comment: Var_dump output is now in the topic.

Comment: Are you sure `$cart` is an array and not an object ? If it's the latter, you should use `$cart->name`.

Comment: Maybe you need to post your array as well

Comment: @roberto06 Good point, it's an aray of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$data` is an object and not an array.

`$array['key']` is the notation for accessing an element in an array, but `$object->key` is the one for an object.

Try this :

```
foreach ($arrayData as $cart):
    echo '<li>' . $cart->name . ',' . $cart->price . ',' . $cart->amount . '</li>';
endforeach;
```

If that doesn't work (due to the private nature of the elements), you might have to declare functions like `getName()`, `getPrice()` and `getAmount()` in your object class file, and use them as such :

```
foreach ($arrayData as $cart):
    echo '<li>' . $cart->getName(). ',' . $cart->getPrice(). ',' . $cart->getAmount(). '</li>';
endforeach;
```

Example of declaration for the function `getName()`, in your object class file :

```
public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}
```

Comment: Changed the data-type to public and used the first one. Works just fine, thanks.

Comment: if he put `Output from var_dump` in starting It will be solved very early.

Comment: Not to be controversial, but this answer its made after I edited my answer.. And I have -2...

Comment: @user2078421 Roberto's answer is better explained; yours has too many "try this" (it's considered as guessing) and is considered as being very low-quality by Stack's standards. There's no need for sour grapes here.

Comment: @user2078421 If I wanted to go there, I could tell you that your answer edit is not only incomplete, but also happened after my comment on OP's question. But I don't.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes. I get data from a database, make a local object from the data, then put it in an array of objects, this was the last step (printing it out)

Comment: @Jeppezon I see. Well, I'm glad to see you got your final solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explain. Good to know. But don't think a negative score its appropriate in this case.. Neutral would be better :)

Comment: @user2078421 I think the downvotes happened before your edit, your answer was way off at that time. I believe (someone correct me if I'm wrong) the proper way to deal with that would've been to delete your answer and recreate one that was actually right, instead of changing it completely `;)`

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure $arrayData is not an Object Data?
In this case try to use $cart->name.

Comment: you went and totally changed your answer from http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42137871/1 where you should have indicated that your original answer wasn't the solution.

Comment: Stack pro tip: the first half of your (new/present) answer  is asking a question for clarification which belongs in a comment. The second half of your answer is considered as guessing and to further ask the OP to try something, which IMHO is also considered another comment. Had you posted that in a comment and it would have solved the question, then the OP could have invited you to post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll do better next time ;)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm actually trying to help you here and to provide better answers and this for future visitors to the question/answer. It's not too late to edit your answer and to change it to better explain what's going on. There's nothing wrong in stating possible scenarios as Roberto did for this answer. However, giving concrete answers to the exact problem is always a given ;-) Remember this for future answers. You may not get the "green tick" but it could very well attract positive votes that the OP/others may see as being useful.